How to run "gradlew runClient" in debug mode?
I am writing a mod for Minecraft.
I use neoforged/NeoGradle. I can run Minecraft client with my mod by

gradlew runClient

I know that the mod works, because I can see it in the game.
I use IntellijIdea as IDE. And my break points in it don't work.
How to run "gradlew runClient" in debug mode?
